# Intercept invalid email during lost_password

Tags: customization, password

On the website I'm developing, I need all login-related forms to be on custom, branded pages. I have pretty much covered them all, but I have just one case I can't manage correctly.

I have set a custom page for the *Lost password?* page, by adding the filter below, then creating a new page with a custom template that renders the *Insert email to get the link* form.

```
function custom_lost_password_page( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/lost-password/' );
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'custom_lost_password_page', 10, 2 );
```

On the page template I set a custom `redirect_to` input field so that the successful request redirects to my custom login page with a specific message.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?= site_url('/login?resetlink=sent') ?>">
```

So far so good. What I can't seem to intercept, is when the user enter a non-existent email. In that case, no matter what, I get redirected to `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`, which is a native WP page we don't want, with the corresponding error message.

[image: Invalid email screen]

I can't seem to find an action or filter to latch onto in this particular case. Google unfortunately wasn't of help and all similar questions here don't seem to handle this very specific case.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'lost_password', 'wpse316932_redirect_wrong_email' );
function wpse316932_redirect_wrong_email() {
    global $errors;

    if ( $error = $errors->get_error_code() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'lost-password/?error=' . $error );
    } else {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'lost-password/' );
    }    
}
```

This is utilizing the [`lost_password` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/lost_password/) that fires right before the lost password form.

You were experiencing this because WP will only redirect you to the url you specified in `redirect_to` input field when there is no errors. If it finds errors in processing the form (which is the obvious case here), it simply continues with rendering the form on the `wp-login.php` page. By using this action you can hook into this procedure right before that.

Comment: Thanks @dboris! That's exactly what I've come up with. I will see if there's some more "native" way to do this, otherwise I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: @GigiSan You are welcome. I edited my answer to include the actual error that is found by WP.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily found a workaround of some sort, but it's not really accurate so **I'm still open to ideas**. :)

I removed the filter

```
function custom_lost_password_page( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/lost-password/' );
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'custom_lost_password_page', 10, 2 );
```

and added an action on `lost_password` instead

```
function custom_lost_password_page() {
    // If the referrer is lost-password then it's a failed attempt,
    // show the form again with an error
    if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'lost-password')) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/lost-password?error=invalidemail'));    
    }
    else {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/lost-password/'));
    }
}
add_action( 'lost_password', 'custom_lost_password_page', 10, 0 );
```

As you can see, it intercepts all calls from itself, masking any possible error as an `invalidemail` error. It suits the purpose, but it's not very clean.

Comment: I believe you can access the global `$errors` variable that holds the `WP_Errors` object inside your function. From there you can dynamically set the error code in your get parameter. Check my updated answer.